# Picasso OOM issue with large images

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, picasso, android-bitmap

I am loading a bunch of images in listview with picasso. I started getting OOM excpetions which was expected since i was just loading them without resize or fit.

All the images are downloaded form internet and some of them are small but some are exceptionally big. I cant use fit() or size easily since i want the images to keep an aspect ration based on the image view width which is set to match parent, and height is wrap content. I have read that i should create a custom transform object but the issue is that i dont know the image view width in list views getView method (its reported as 0 since it still not messured)

**First question:**  Does picasso resize the actuall images on disk when using resize or fit? Or does it keep them with their downloaded size and then resizes them upon loading.
**Note: I tired fixing for example .resize(300,300) but still got OOM when loading that large image. 5615x374 is the size :)**    thats why i am asking if picasso resizes the image on disk.

**Seccond Question:** How to fix the OOM, try to get screen size and use it for image view size in custom transformation and preserve the aspect ratio? Or what to do when faced with images this big...my phone is htc desire with just 512 ram 4.0 android.

Comment: There's an Android limitation at play - BitmapFactory can't load images larger than 4096x4096, so I guess it'd need to be resized on disk too. Not sure if how webview and the browsers do it.

Comment: Thanks, so i guess then picasso doesnt resize images on disk...

Comment: You can always query for smaller images from the server, if the server supports that sort of thing. What good is it to load a 5615x374 image in the tiny view of a ListView anyway?

Comment: Unfortunately the server doesnt support querying for smaller images...the images are part of "articles" which are published by writers and they dont pay attention when publishing images. Sometimes they are 300x300 sometimes 5k x 3k.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to all my questions is: https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/API

specifically: https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading

I have found some tickets at Picasso GitHub with same issues, but unfortunatelly they were never resolved...No custom transformation could help me with Picasso since i needed to resize the image upon download.

AndroidQuery handled all that, plus it proved to be much much better performance vise. Also i personally find the interface to be as good as Picasso's if not better. Also AQuerry has many other usefull functions that Picasso doesnt offer.